# MVVM Datagrid nesting

Tags: datagrid, nested

I have a data grid where in i have to display an image and again a datagris which has to display messages. I could bind the parent datagrid and image is getting displayed but the inner datagrid is not bound and neither displaying any error.

Am i missing anything? Here is my xaml

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Col1}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells" Header="Column1" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate  >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                    <Image   Source="{Binding ImagePathItem1}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="250" Width="250">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells" Header="Column2">
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageData}" Foreground="Orange"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </StackPanel>                                                                        
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                       
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The Col1 collection is bound to parent datasource and the data is available for all other controls.

Comment: You binding seems incomplete on the inner datagrid: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`

Comment: if i give same binding as that of parent grid it says binding expression error...

Comment: What is "Col1" ? Could you add some code-behind code as well ?

Comment: Col1 is my observable collection of objects...            public ObservableCollection<MyCollectionClass> Col1 
        {
            get
            {
                return m_oCol1;
            }
            set
            {
                m_oCol1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Col1);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting what is the binding and in your example, the binding expression is incomplete: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`.

As you said in your comment, `Col1`is an `ObservableCollection<MyCollectionClass>`. What would be interesting to see is the class itself, but anyway.

When you bind *Col1* to your parent DataGrid, the **properties of the class** are available to the child controls for binding (for each item in your collection). If there is again no such *Col1* property in *MyCollectionClass*, you can't bind it to the inner DataGrid !

Imagine you have the following class (simplified):

```
public class MyCollectionClass {

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

}
ObservableCollection<MyCollectionClass> Col1;
```

You can then bind this way:

```
ParentDataGrid: {Binding Col1)
     TextBox: {Binding Firstname}
     TextBox: {Binding Lastname}
     InnerDataGrid: {Binding Col1} // You can't do that
```

For each instance of your class in your collection, you'll have a row in your DataGrid with *Firstname* and *Lastname* because they are public properties of the class. But not with *Col1*.

Comment: thnx Didier... this helped a lot.. i tried keeping separate collection as property of Col1 and bind that to child grid.